# Terser uglifies process.env in Node.js environment, making it unusable

Tags: node.js

I would like to use the package [Terser](https://github.com/terser-js/terser) (basically UglifyJS for ES6+) in a Node.js environment. I'm using `webpack` and `terser-webpack-plugin` with these options:

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        parallel: true,
        terserOptions: {
          ecma: 6,
          toplevel: true,
          keep_classnames: false,
          keep_fnames: false,
          mangle: {
            properties: true
          }
        },
      }),
    ]
  },
```

When setting `mangle.properties` to `true`, the plugin mangles `process.env` to something like `r.es`, therefore breaking it when trying to access it with `r.es['NODE_ENV']` or similar code. Check out this code that terser produced:

```
"use strict";
(function(t) {
    Object.defineProperty(e, "l", {
        h: !0
    });
    const n = i(1)
      , s = i(45)
      , r = i(78);
    e.ts = (t=>parseInt(r.es[t] || "")); // r.es should be r.env or process.env
    let o = e.ts("LOG_LEVEL");
    isNaN(o) && (o = n.ss.ns);
    class c {
    }
    c.rs = e.ts("API_PORT") || 9e3,
    c.os = r.es.cs || "0.0.0.0",
    c.us = "YES" === r.es.hs,
    c.ls = o,
    c.fs = e.ts("LOG_ROWS_TO_KEEP") || 1e5,
    c.ys = s.join(c.ds, "build"),
    e.a = c
}
).call(this, "/")
```

I can fix this when setting `mangle.properties` to `false`, but I would really like to turn it on.

Importing or requiring `process` was the first thing I tried, but the output from terser didn't change at all.

```
const process = require('process');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially thought it would be sufficient to reserve `process`, but turns out, it wasn't.

Instead, I came up with this:

```
mangle: {
  properties: {
    keep_quoted: true,
    reserved: [ 'process', 'env' ],
  }
}
```

It's a bit of a hack, because it also disables mangling `foo.env`, for instance.

Comment: I tried that with `['process', 'env', 'process.env']`, it doesn't work however. Do you think I should open an issue on the terser github page?

Comment: @dislick sorry, I spoke too soon. See edit (it doesn't look like it's possible to protect "process.env" entirely, but there's a workaround that might be acceptable).